# Implicit lookup for Typeclass of None is not compatible with Contravariant Typeclass of Option

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicits

I don't get the following code to compile and I am curious of what I did wrong.

I defined a Contravariant Jsonwriter Trait and a function accepting implicit writers:

```
trait JsonWriter[-A] {
  def write(value: A): Json
}

object Json {
  def toJson[A](value: A)(implicit writer: JsonWriter[A]): Json =
  writer.write(value)
}
```

Additionally I have defined some instances of these writers:

```
object JsonWriterInstances {
  implicit val stringWriter: JsonWriter[String] =
    (value: String) => JsString(value)

  implicit val doubleWriter: JsonWriter[Double] =
    (value: Double) => JsNumber(value)

  class OptionWriter[-T](writer: JsonWriter[T]) extends JsonWriter[Option[T]] {
    def write(value: Option[T]): Json = {
        value match {
          case None    => JsNull
          case Some(x) => writer.write(x)
        }
      }
  }
  implicit def optionWriter[T](implicit writer: JsonWriter[T]):
      JsonWriter[Option[T]] = new OptionWriter[T](writer)

}
```

Now I have written a test:

```
"write double Option" in {
  Some(1.0).toJson should be(JsNumber(1.0))
  None.toJson should be(JsNull)
}
```

The first test for Some(1.0) works fine 
The second one for None throws:

```
Error:(40, 12) could not find implicit value for parameter writer: JsonWriter[None.type]
    None.toJson should be(JsNull)
```

If you want to try the code my JsonType definitions for this example are:

```
sealed trait Json

final case class JsObject(get: Map[String, Json]) extends Json

final case class JsString(get: String) extends Json

final case class JsNumber(get: Double) extends Json

case object JsNull extends Json
```

Comment: `None` does not help when inference is bad, why `Option.empty[T]` can be useful/recommenced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`None`, if you dont say anything else, is a `Option[Nothing]`, so `OptionWriter[Nothing]` needs a `JsonWriter[Nothing]`. If you try `Json.toJson(Some(1))` is the same, there is no `JsonWriter[Int]`.

On the other hand, `Json.toJson(None:Option[String])` works, because OptionWriter[String] can get a JsonWriter[String].

Comment: Nice, that explains it, however, when I add a JsonWriter[Nothing] due to contravariance my code can't decide anylonger whether to take JsonWriter[String] or JsonWriter[Nothing]. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd been trying diff approaches, as you say, Nothing and contravariance is a problem. The only way a could get it work is giving a type to None. (eg None:Option[String])

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the fact that

```
case object None extends Option[Nothing] { ... }
```

if you do one of the following, it will work

```
toJson(Option.empty[Double])
toJson(None : Option[Double])
```

Note that the second one uses [type ascription](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html) to put a face, so to speak, on the `Nothing` (which is a subtype of everything)